# How to show that the number of diagonals in an $n$-sided polygon is $\frac{n(n - 3)}{2}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A *diagonal* of a polygon is defined to be a line joining any two non-adjacent vertices.

b) How many diagonals are there in 6-sided polygon?

c) Show that the number of diagonals in an $n$-sided polygon is $\dfrac{n(n-3)}{2}$.

In part b what I did $6C2 - 6$?

I am not getting the pattern of part c.. Please help.

Comment: The same idea works ${n\choose 2}-n=n(n-3)/2$

Comment: You first choose any of the n vertices, then choose any of the $n-3$ other non adjacent vertices, but since we’ve double counted we divide by 2.

Comment: Please write a title that is specific to the question.  Your answer to part (b) is correct.